# JqueryUI Dropdown Menu Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Hi I am having problem fixing this menu of mine below is the actual image and code any suggestion is well appriciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu();
        });
</script>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Main Tab</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This is link A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is link B</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting[image]
what I like is[image]
I am using jqueryUI I tried .menu() attributes or parameters but still nothing change. I wonder if I can achieve it by just altering css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it, this is the link 
http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/sS93F/

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left-1 top+35" } });
        });
```

some manipulation of menu widget for JqueryUI found Here :
http://api.jqueryui.com/menu

Comment: This solution would be more flexible using the height of the menu element to set the position.

var usermenu = $("#usermenu");
usermenu.menu({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left top+"+usermenu.height() } });

Comment: @Raanan True, and there's also always `position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom" }`.  [JQuery UI - Position API](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li > ul {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Should do the trick

See: http://jsfiddle.net/mF9sJ/

Comment: it works absolutely but the jqueryUI keeps flagging the child menu to right not bottom, violating my css :( Thanks for response Sir

Comment: Can you post an jsfiddle example?

Comment: I fixed it jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/sS93F/ got a solution by the help of this api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position Thanks S.Visser I will use your css. :)